# dataLayer Control Automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-datalayer, data-layers

- String dataLayer = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer);");

Hello friends, I want make dataLayer testing automation with java and selenium.İf you know basic way for this testing with automation. I wonder your way.